# i18next default language setting to en-ZA instead of en-US

Tags: i18next

I have english and chinese translations for use with i18next in my web app. Now, with the below code, I wanted it to be en-US as default Language and have option to change to chinese. But when i look up the Local Storage variable for i18nextLng, the value is en-ZA. Why is the default english not setting to en-US.

Please let me know where I am wrong. Thanks.

Below is the code I used:

```
i18next
  .use(i18nextXHRBackend)
  .use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    ns: ['menu', 'translate'],
    defaultNS: 'translate',
    backend: {

      loadPath: '/assets/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      crossDomain: false
    }
  }, function(err, t) {
    // init set content
    updateContent();
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currently your config only sets `fallbackLng` which is "just" used if the detected language from detector (=> en-ZA from localStorage) is found.

To manually override detection set `lng` on init or use `i18next.changeLanguage`.

Comment: Hi @jamuhl, i tried putting lng: en in js in login page. But the problem with that is, if a user will select chinese on login page and browses pages after login. And then he signs out and comes to login page, instead of chinese, the language changes to english. Is there a solution for that? Like until the session is active, keep it in the language of choice for the user?

Comment: so basically you do not want detection...? then do not set lng on init and config lng detector to not detect but only cache: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector#detector-options